# How to avoid space at the end of string using maskRe in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs

I have a text field where user should be able to leave space at the end of string, but they can have between two letters. I used

```
maskRe:/[^\s]/
```

but this is blocking user from entering space in between letters. How to do it?

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew noticed, `maskRe` just prevents invalid keystrokes, but does not check order. For checking order you may use a validate function. See here for an answer of him with a demo https://stackoverflow.com/a/40740754/7500028 So, for maskRe you should allow spaces. (you may even remove maskRe?), and for validation you could use `\S$`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this for checking that it ends with no-space character: `\S$`

Where `$` means end of string/line. And `\S` is negated-`\s` (which is any sort of whitespace)

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4drta/1/)**

Also, use `regex:` instead of `maskRe:`

Comment: It won't work since `maskRe` only runs the regex against the typed char and is totally unaware of the context where this char is being input. Here is a related [blog post](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?232522-How-to-set-up-regex-and-maskre&p=860560&viewfull=1#post860560).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I'll remove my answer. I added that info to a comment on the main question and referenced some answer of yours on a similar question.

Comment: Well, you may just use `regex:`  field and keep the answer. We do not know what OP really is after: live validation or final onsubmit validation.